# Локальный сервер для веб разработки на windows

Tags: php, docker, openserver

Всем привет, работу над веб проектами я веду локально. На OpenServer. 
Теперь встала необходимость, создать контейнер для проекта, чтобы другие разработчики в т.ч. и я, могли быстро локально развернуть проект со всем окружением.

Насколько я понял это можно сделать через докер.

Но, насколько я понял, это будет в виртуальной машине, к которой нужно подключаться как к обычному серверу. 
И получается, локальный файлов (как в OpenServer) у меня не будет, и я не смогу через среду разработку PHPStorm или другие, открыть полностью проект? 
или как это работает?

Comment: У laravel есть готовое решение. Называется Laravel Homestead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам по себе Докер - не про виртуализацию.

Но при разработке придется использовать Docker Desktop

Как это будет выглядит?(один из самых частых случаев)

У вас есть проект. Ваши локальные файлы. Есть специальный файл(проект) docker-compose, который ваши проекты запускает. В данном случае каждый проект(сервер) будет docker файлов. В docker-compose вы настраиваете их работу друг с другом.

Вывод: в целом будет все выглядеть так же, как и раньше(локально проект скачали и начали работать), но внутри не так.

Ключевые слова для гуглежа: docker-compose, .dockerfile, Docker Desktop, как работает docker-compose, почему docker не про виртуализация

Comment: @234234 если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как ответ(галочка около ответа). Так пользователя могут понять, что есть ответ и что он помог задающему вопрос.